# How can I fetch and print the current active tab information

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to extract the title and URL of the web page of my current active tab.

I'm getting error --( Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: "#lol".text is not a function
)

I tried this

```
(manifest)
 {
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "My Launcher",
"description": "Quick launch lol Media",
"version": "1.0.0",
"icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["activeTab"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"],
    "persistent": false
   }
  }

  (popup.html)
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="popup.js">
    </script>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="greet">mc</h2>
    <h3 id="lol">url</h3> 
    <h4 id = "card"></h4>
</body>

</html>


 (popup.js)
  chrome.tabs.query({"active": true, "currentWindow": true}, 
   function (tabs) 
 {
   var tabURL = tabs.url;
   ('#lol').text(tabURL);

 });
```

I want to show the URL in popup when the user clicks on the extension icon.

Comment: You're missing `$` before `('#lol')`.

Comment: i tried that too same error

Comment: Ah, you also need to move the line that loads jQuery before your other script line in popup.html.

Comment: I tried that but jQuery is still not loading. However i got my answer i am getting the URL in the popup. I just modified(('#lol').text(tabURL); --> document.getElementById("lol").textContent=tablink;)